# Debugging Heap/Stack and Memory Issues on IAR Workbench for STM32F4x

Tags: c++, debugging, heap-memory, iar, stack-memory

I am testing a program in C/C++. When running without optimization, the program is not behaving properly. Some variables are set to 0 in the middle of the program.

When I compiled the program with optimization enabled, the application runs properly.

I would like to know how I can detect/address this issue. Not sure if it is related to Stack/Heap memory allocation or other issue.

I am working with IAR Workbench 8.20 and the STM32F407 Chip

Comment: Since the problem occurs when compiling without optimizations, enable debugging and try to find the location where the program misbeahaves by using break-points and single-stepping.

Comment: My stupid trick: Stub out the hardware-specific stuff as low as you can go and try to run the code in linux where you can hit it with the likes of valgrind. Pick off as much of the application logic issues as you can before going to the hardware.